# connecting remote devices using prefrences

Tags: android, android-preferences, android-bluetooth

I am trying to get information about the last remote bluetooth device for re-pairing,
but i keep getting a null String.

this is the code im using:

```
String lastUsedRemoteDevices = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE).getString("LAST_REMOTE_DEVICE_ADDRESS", null);
if (lastUsedRemoteDevices!=null){
    Log.d("TAL","checking for last used remote devices");
    Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = adapter.getBondedDevices();        
    for (BluetoothDevice pDevice: pairedDevices){
         if (pDevice.getAddress().equals(lastUsedRemoteDevices)){               
             Log.d("TAL","foud device: "+pDevice.getName());
             remoteDevice = pDevice;            
             connectionEstablished==true;
         }
     }}
```

now im assuming the Stringresult is null because i dont get the log post.
any ideas why it's not working.

Comment: in this code you are trying to read but where is your code for saving data.